# Level Sets in R3 (3rd dimension)

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Which of the following can be a level set in R3 out of an empty set, a point, a curve, and a surface?

I know that for 3 variables in R3 it's a surface, but what about 2 variables in R3?
And am I wrong in assuming that an empty set can be a level set in any dimension, Rn?

Answer (score 1):

Any non-empty closed set in any dimension is a level set of the function that measures the distance to (the closest point in) that set. Points, curves, surfaces and more. The empty set is, among other things, the level set of $\|\mathbf x\|=-1$.

Comment: i see, thank you